# Sum up two values from two sub procedures in the same cell with vba

Tags: excel, vba

Here you go the two subroutines of which I would like to sum up their value in the same cell.

```
Sub CheckBox126_Click()

If (Count = Null) Then
    Count = 0
End If

Count = 0

If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 126").ControlFormat = xlOn Then Count = Count + 2
Range("C29").Value = Count

End Sub

'second routine

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C29")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = "Orange" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1
    ElseIf Target.Value = "Dark orange/brown" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1
    ElseIf Target.Value = "Pink" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 2
    ElseIf Target.Value = "Red" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 2
    ElseIf Target.Value <> "" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0
    Else
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

I would like combine their value in the same cell. Please can you help me with this. Many thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you want to add together, can you give an example?

Comment: As you can see the two procedures give two different values:

Comment: Your first function only seems to put 0 or 2 into the Cell C29, depending upon the value of the checkbox. Is this what it is supposed to do?

Comment: yes it is only 0 or 2 in the first checkbox function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function like this:

```
Function CheckBox126() As Integer
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 126").ControlFormat = xlOn Then
        CheckBox126 = 2
    else
        CheckBox126 = 0
    End If
End Function
```

At the end of your second procedure add:

```
Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Offset(0, 1).Value + CheckBox126()
```

The function will check the status of checkbox126, returning 2 or 0 and the second procedure adds this value on at the end.

Comment: with function checkbox is giving syntax error on Return 0 and Return 2, they both of them marked in red even though I have added then to xlOn

Comment: Sorry, got my syntax confused (too much C# lately). It works now, I've tested it.

Comment: Run time error 1004 on If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 126").ControlFormat = xlOn Then

Comment: After I have checked the box the system get frozen with that error

Comment: I copied that from your formula. Did it work before the extra code?

Comment: Ok let me try again without spaces

Comment: I don't know why you are getting an error 1004. The possible reasons are: CheckBox126 is not on the ActiveSheet at the time of executing the code OR the Checkbox is not called "Check Box 126".

Comment: Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Offset(0, 1).Value + CheckBox126() repeat the result endlessly on the row.  While adding simply the checkbox fuction to the main procedure return the value I want. It's strange but the concept is the one you have showed me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

So this is confusing. Someone checks a checkbox, then you check the value of `Count`, and set it to 0 if the condition is met. Then you set it to 0 anyway.

If the checkbox was ticked, its set to 2, if unticked, it stays as 0.

Then you set a cell to be the value of count, which will trigger `Worksheet_Change`, which it looks like you tried to set up so it will only trigger on a change to the cell that you changed above, so why not add it to the same subroutine?

Then you assume that the changed target is a single cell, and check its value for a color value. But as we know that if it is a single cell, to get to this point, that single cell has to be C29, the cell you changed to either 0 or 2 above, then we know the the value is the same as the value of count, so none of these conditions will ever match...

...Unless the cell C29 is change manually to a color, but in that case, you don't have 2 numbers to add.

I would suggest relooking at all of your code and rephrasing this question.

To actually answer your question, just add this to the bottom of the second routine:

`Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Offset(0, 1).Value + Range("C29").Value`